# Why won't this low pass filter work in spice?

Tags: spice, ngspice

I just started working with spice and I feel like I'm making some sort of obvious mistake but unsure what.

This works fine:

```
R1 in out 1k
R2 out 0 1k
Vin in 0 dc 0 ac 1 sin(0 1 500)

.control
ac dec 1000 10 15kHz
plot 20*log(out/in)
.endc

.end
```

(As in the simulation runs, but it gives me something strange for the gain) Certainly it makes no sense to do a frequency analysis on a simple voltage divider, but it's just a sanity check for the real circuit I'm trying to simulate:

```
R1 in out 1k
C1 out 0 100nF
Vin in 0 dc 0 ac 1 sin(0 1 500)

.control
ac dec 1000 10 15kHz
plot 20*log(out/in)
.endc

.end
```

I simply replace R2 with a 100 nF capacitor, and the simulation fails.

The first error I get is:

```
Warning: singular matrix:  check nodes out and out
```

This doesn't make any sense to me.

I feel like perhaps I'm doing something wrong with the "Vin" line, as I'm not exactly sure how the "ac" line knows to change Vin (since it's not ever referenced on that line) I am simply trying to sweep 1V AC from 10 hz to 15kHz.

Comment: I think you mix transient analysis (.TRAN directive) and ac analysis (.AC directive). The statement for \$V_{in}\$ specifies a sinusoidal source which is a transient generator. It is ok if you want to observe the output in transient analysis for linear and nonlinear circuits (though SPICE will linearize them anyway). However, I believe you want an ac analysis to plot the transfer function of a linear circuit. In this case, \$V_{in}\$ should be *Vin in 0 ac=1* (dc is zero by default without a dc keyword).

Comment: What you did looks OK to me as well, your filter simulation should just work. What I would try is to add a high value resistor (like 10 Mega ohm) in parallel with C1. That resistor would have little influence on the filter function but could help with finding the DC operating point which might be the issue. But it's the simulator at fault as I know that some simulators work perfectly fine with your circuit.

Comment: @VerbalKint Your comment is not correct. Having the sin(0 1 500) at the end is **not** a problem. In ac analysis, that part is just discarded. ```Vin in 0 dc 0 ac 1 sin(0 1 500)``` just works.

Comment: @Huisman, oops, you're right, I had overlooked the ac keyword in the command line. Good catch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues regarding your code:

- In both examples, you end the section with `.end`. But this `.end` defines the **end** of the netlist, but you didn't (purposely) define the **start** of the netlist.
  The parser now will parse `R1 in out 1k` as **title**, so there is no conenction between node "in" and node "out", leaving a floating out node.
  That will give you the `Warning: singular matrix:  check nodes out and out`
  You can solve this by starting with plain text as first line, or even a white line will do, or use the .title statement.
- You use `plot` to plot a bode diagram, `plot` only plots the **real** part, not the **magnitude**.
  Use plot `vdb(out)` and `plot ph(out)` instead.

So, I'd suggest to change your code to

```
Just plain text here, or even a white line will do, or use the .title statement
R1 in out 1k
C1 out 0 100nF
Vin in 0 dc 0 ac 1 sin(0 1 500)

.control
ac dec 1000 10 15kHz
plot vdb(out)
plot ph(out)
.endc

.end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!! It works perfectly now! :)